# Can't press on react-native markers maps

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps-markers, marker

I use `BubbleMenu` in my `react-native` project and I'm in trouble with react native marker.

In all my map markers I want to show when the user press it a `BubbleMenu`
this is my work:

```
<MapView.Marker
  coordinate={marker.coordinate}
  title={marker.title}
  description={marker.description}
  onCalloutPress={this.markerClick}
>
  <MapView.Callout tooltip style={styles.customView}>
    <BubbleMenu
      items={items}
      openBtn={openBtn}
      show={show}
      style={styles.menu}
    />
  </MapView.Callout>
</MapView.Marker>
```

When I click on my marker I can see my bubble menu but I can't click on it 
any Idea?

Comment: did you add `onPress` on  `Callout`: `<MapView.Callout tooltip style={styles.customView} onPress={() => {somthing here}}>`

Comment: i can click on it but not select the button inside